# Play music over Skype?

Tags: skype, music

I want to be able to play Music (or general SFX) during a Skype call when talking with some friends.

I have a Chromebook, and they have Windows.

Is it even possible? And if so, how would I, or what software would I need to download? With my basic knowledge and research, a Virtual Audio Cable is what I could use, right?

If it is, I can't seem to find one for Chromebook!

Big thanks for the help!

Comment: If you're the one trying to do this, your friend's system is irrelevant. Your system would have to support system audio as part of a mic input. VAC only runs on Mac and Windows, so Chromebook is out of the question. Questions specifically asking what software to install are off topic on this site, so please keep that in mind. The simplest method would be to have a 2nd device playing the music at an appropriate volume where your mic can pick it up.

Comment: Thank you for the advice and information, and apologies, I wasn't aware, I shall keep it in mind. Thanks again! Appreciate it